# Zend File rename after uploading zend form

Tags: php, file, zend-framework

I'm not getting the information I am looking for from research. I'd like to perform a `rename` on the file upload after it has uploaded. I need the original filename as well as renaming it. Here is what I have so far:

```
    $form = new Sam_Form_Database($this->resource);
    $form->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
            $data = $form->getValues();
            try {
                    $form->fileelement->receive();
                    $originalFilename = pathinfo($form->fileelement->getFileName());
                    $newFilename = Sam_Util::generateHash().'.'.$originalFilename['extension'];
                    $filterFileRename = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array(
                            'target' => $newFilename,
                            'overwrite' => true,
                            'keepExtension' => true
                    ));
                    $filterFileRename->filter($form->fileelement->getFileName());
                } catch(Exception $e){
                    Sam::exception("Cannot upload file");
                }   
            Sam_Util::insertDataIntoDatabase($data,$this->resource);
            Sam_Util::redirectSimple('list');
        }
```

The problems:

- nothing seems to be uploading
- before when it was uploading it wasn't renaming the file in the destination

What I need is a fluent way to handle uploading, retrieving the original filename, and performing a rename on the target file using zend.